# How do I check how long authentication/login time takes on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I check how long in took for a user to connect to a database in SQL Server?

I can get login time and name etc from sys.dm_exec_sessions but how do I get the authentication/connection (elapsed) time

Comment: why would you need to measure this? should be pretty instantaneous...

Comment: I have a developer that wants to know, not sure why to be honest. I thought it would be simple but after mulling it over it would seem not :s

Comment: "I have a developer that wants to know" - so ask them why! You can pretty much be sure the real problem is something else

Comment: ok so its not a problem as such but they need end to end times for a client SLA requirement. they need "time it took to connect", 2how long it was connected"

Comment: 0.1% / 99.9% .... A better solution is for the devs to instrument their code: better granularity, more control of metrics etc...

Comment: so there is no log of this? i.e on oracle you can check "request time" and "actual connection time" on the listner log

Comment: You could try capturing the login time in SQL Profiler but it's only one event. I guess the other event time would be when the code  requests. I don't think it's something you can actually measure.